# How to pass data from one event listener to another using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decimal, calculator, point

I have made a calculator using JS, the number pad elements with the values from 1-9 are triggered using an event listener.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item-number');
```

These display on my screen element

```js
let display = document.getElementById('show');
```

These all work fine, my issue is with the decimal point button, in which I originally tried to assign an event listener. This worked fine if i press the decimal button and then press a number button

eg; 0.2
but when i press number first then decimal i get the same as above.

I'm fairly new to JS and have tried many different ways to try and solve this, such as using concat etc

```js
const itemDecimal = document.querySelector('.item-operator__decimal');
```

Comment: All you've shown is how you query elements in the document. Without seeing the code that handles events and how it updates your display, this is impossible to answer

Comment: event listeners are just functions whose first argument is an Event object

Answer (score 0):

```
const itemNumbers = document.querySelectorAll('.item-number');
const itemDecimal = document.querySelector('.item-operator__decimal');

const itemClear = document.querySelector('.item-clear__recent');
const itemClearAll = document.querySelector('.item-clear__all');

let display = document.getElementById('show');

let outPutTextElements;

itemNumbers.forEach(item => {
    let itemTxtNumbers = [item.innerHTML]; // get string numbers 1-9 values

    item.addEventListener('click',function(){ 
        outPutTextElements= 
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML += itemTxtNumbers; // display incremented element
        
        let number = parseFloat(outPutTextElements); // prevent zero from appending to front
        number % 1 == 0 ? number.toFixed(0): number.toFixed(1);
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = number; 
        
    });
});

itemDecimal.addEventListener('click',function(decimal){
    let decimalPoint = decimal.target.innerText;
    display.innerText = decimalPoint;
})
```

Below is the html

```html
<div class="screen" id="show">
  <button class="item item-number">7</button>
  <button class="item item-number">8</button>
  <button class="item item-number">9</button>
  <button class="item item-clear__recent">CE</button>
  <div class="item item-clear__all">C</div>

  <button class="item item-number">4</button>
  <button class="item item-number">5</button>
  <button class="item item-number">6</button>
  <button class="item item-operator">/</button>
  <button class="item item-operator">*</button>

  <button class="item item-number">1</button>
  <button class="item item-number">2</button>
  <button class="item item-number">3</button>
  <button class="item item-operator">-</button>
  <button class="item item-operator">+</button>

  <button class="item item-number item-number__zero">0</button>
  <button class="item item-operator__decimal">.</button>
  <button class="item item-operator__equals">=</button>
</div>
```